# How to split a string on multiple delimiters stored in a list?

Tags: java

I have a list of delimiters like

```
List<String> delimiters= Arrays.asList(",",".");
```

If I have a string like `"a.b,c"`.

How to split on all the delimiters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check below code whether it solves your problem:

```
List<String> delimiters = Arrays.asList(",", ".", "?", ":");

for (String delimiter : delimiters) {
  text = text.replace(delimiter, " "); //replace all delimiter occurrence with space
}

String[] output = text.split(" "); //split using space
```

Comment: This will fail if you have strings containing a space in your list. Better: replace with a known delimiter, eg delimiters.get(0), instead of space

Answer (score 2):

You can do a regular expression.

```
@Test
public void test() {
    List<String> delimiters = Arrays.asList(",", ".", "?");
    String str = "a.b,c?dr";

    StringBuilder regex = new StringBuilder();
    regex.append("[");
    delimiters.stream().forEach(delimiter -> regex.append(delimiter + "/"));
    regex.append("]");

    String[] result = str.split(regex.toString());
}
```

Comment: Note that this does not account for delimiters with multiple characters.

Comment: You did probably mean `|` instead of `/`?

Answer (score 0):

```
    String s = "a.b,c";
    String[] split = s.split("[.|,]");
```

how about this? Use “|” to separate multiple delimiters， remember to add [], Otherwise it needs to be escaped

Comment: There might be more delimiters in the list

Comment: You are missing an important part of the question when you are hard coding the delimiters instead of using the `delimiters` list

Answer (score 0):

Here is code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class StringSplitMultipleDelimeter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> delimiters= Arrays.asList(",",".","!","?","$","&","^","%","@");
        String givenString = "Test,String.with?Multiple@delimeters!example";
        //Create Regex to split sting
        StringBuilder regex = new StringBuilder();
        regex.append("[");
        delimiters.forEach(delimeter -> regex.append(delimeter));
        regex.append("]");
        String[] tokens = givenString.split(regex.toString());
        System.out.println("Number of tokens = " + tokens.length);
        for(int i =0; i<tokens.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(tokens[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use replaceAll on the string first and convert it all to a fixed delimiter (your choice) like this - then you can split it based on that:

```
String[] newArray = stringArray.replaceAll("[\\.]", ",").split(",");
```

Comment: Nitpicking, but there's no need to convert `,` to `,` as well. Also, `,` doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: You are missing an important part of the question when you are hard coding the delimiters instead of using the `delimiters` list